# How to merge two code bases with Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, bitbucket

I'm in a tracked situation. I've got a larger project (A) on Github. Then I took a copy of the complete code, created a Git repo (B) on Bitbucket (because it can be private).

I made some changes on B which shouldn't be public and so stay on the Bitbucket repo. But the community pulled some new code on A.

How to merge the new changes on A into B?

```
Repo A (Github):    R1a => R2a => R3a => R4a => R5a => R6a
                            ↓                           ↓?
Repo B (Bitbucket):        R2a => R3b ===============> R4b
```

So at version R2a I copied the code base to Bitbucket. Then I developed R3b on Bitbucket. During and after that on Github the version R3a, R4a, R5a and R6a were developed. How to merge those changes/versions two R3b to create the merged R4b?

I know, that this won't be an automatic process because of conflicts. But how to merge from A to B exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git lets you [add remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). So, for example here, in a clone of B,

```
git remote add A https://url-to-A
```

Then, you can git fetch A and merge the branch you want in with

```
git merge A/branch
```

In other words, you're doing manually for a different remote what a git pull does by default on origin/your-branch